# How to allow right or middle clicked to open in a new tab or window

Tags: html, angularjs

Here is the js method:

```
scope.onTheClick = function(source, item, $event) {
          if (!_.isUndefined(scope.helpers) && !_.isUndefined(scope.helpers.onTheClick)) {
            scope.helpers.onTheClick(item);
          } else if (source) {
            if ($event.metaKey) {
              window.open('/'+ source + '/' + item.id);
            } else {
              window.location.href = '/'+ source + '/' + item.id;
            }
          }
        };
```

right now it works like `ng-click="onTheClick(source, item, $event)" ng-class="[helpers.onTheClass(item)]"`
How can I add right or middle clicked to open in a new tab or window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case **$event.button** stores the mouse button, which has been pressed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Comment: it's not a button. it's a row in a table. what I am trying to do is: I should be able to right click on a row and see the option `Open Link in New Tab`.

Comment: With $event.button you can determine, which mouse-button has been pressed. Instead of if($event.metaKey) you could write if($event.button == 2) for the right button or 3 for middle button.